# Swing formatting issues

Tags: graphics, jframe

In an attempt to create a checkerboard type grid, I found myself frustrated. Coding it was easy enough, but the outcome isn't quite right. I know my code is right because I even had someone else whose a much better programmer than I check it out. The problem is that the first two rows, though alternating, start on the same color. I even tried ignoring it, and hardcoding over it, but whenever I used Color.white for those two rows, it came out black. I'm looking for suggestions as how to fix this problem. Or in case I did make a logical error and neither me or my friend caught it, I'm hoping one of you can.

```
public class Checkers1 extends JFrame {
public void paint(Graphics g){
    //checker-board
    for(int x=0, t=0; x<8 && t>=0; x++,t++){
        for(int y=0; y<8; y++, t++){
            if(t%2==0|| t==0){
                g.fillRect(x*80, y*80, 80, 80);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }
            else{
                g.fillRect(x*80, y*80, 80, 80);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
            }
        }
    }
}
public Checkers1(){
    setSize(640,640);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Checkers1 b=new Checkers1();
}
```

}

Comment: In this code, fillRect goes before setColor. So what color is the first call to fillRect supposed to use? How about swapping the lines, so that the color is set first?

Comment: oh god. xD I'm so blind.